# Are on-policy algorithms always better than off-policy ones?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, off-policy-methods, on-policy-methods

I am studying RL and I have a question: Are **on-policy** algorithms always better than **off-policy** ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An off-policy algorithm is, in one sense, always better. It allows you to train on already collected data that you could otherwise not use.

An off-policy algorithm can be used to "re-interpret" data that was collected earlier while running a worse policy. It can also learn the optimal policy while still doing disruptive random exploration. (Instead of learning to anticipate those random actions and mitigate.)

But in practice, if you can cheaply generate new training episodes (e.g. with a fast simulator), an off-policy algorithm may make the learning more complicated (slower) without any benefit. As always, it depends. Every method has some task for which it is optimal.